# AngularJS - Get objects in select element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to list the all objects in the select element and the first object must be selected by default.

This is the controller to get all objects:

```
$scope.categories = function() {
    $http(
            {
                method : 'GET',
                url : '/prodemo/categories'
            }).success(
                    function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.categories = data;
            }).error(
                    function(data, status, headers, config) {
            });
};
```

And this is the select element:

```
<div data-ng-init="categories()">
    <select ng-model="category" ng-options="category.name for category in categories"> </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Hi, there is no problem with the list, my problem is when I want to set the first object in the select element. I need the select element get the first object by default.

Answer (score 2):

Put this line in your controller:

```
$scope.category = categories[0];
```

It will initialize the first category option as the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would recommend you to use [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) instead of making `$http` calls in controller(s), to make modular, reusable and more testable code. (And what not advantages) Then, perhaps, you should take a look at [controllerAs](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) instead of using $scope.

Setting the default option can be achieved by using the first element of your array as the value of your model.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/cc7B3wCNfe7Ep2UQ0eVV) (without controllerAs) that uses a service and resolves the data when done.